# How to Insert a new Column in SQL based on Window Function Ranking and Condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, conditional-statements, partitioning, ranking

In the table below, 'ranking' was implemented with the `RANK()` function, with something like:

```
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY month, year) as ranking
```

| month | year | car_type | model | sales | ranking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2020 | mercedes | s_class | 2000 | 1 |
| 5 | 2020 | mercedes | s_class | 1500 | 2 |
| 10 | 2020 | bmw | x5 | 7000 | 1 |
| 11 | 2020 | bmw | x5 | 6000 | 2 |
| 12 | 2020 | bmw | x5 | 5000 | 3 |

The desired outcome is to create a feature, e.g. '**best_sales_month**', which will be equal to the number of the 'month' column where 'ranking'=1 *for every respective distinct pair of 'car_type' and 'model'*. It will look like this:

| month | year | car_type | model | sales | ranking | best_sales_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2020 | mercedes | s_class | 2000 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 2020 | mercedes | s_class | 1500 | 2 | 4 |
| 10 | 2020 | bmw | x5 | 7000 | 1 | 10 |
| 11 | 2020 | bmw | x5 | 6000 | 2 | 10 |
| 12 | 2020 | bmw | x5 | 5000 | 3 | 10 |

For example, for BMW x5 cars, 'best_sales_month' is 10 because sales are greater when month=10, for that pair of car_type and model.

Currently, I've reached this point:

```
CASE 
  -- when ranking=1, grab the value of 'month' for that entry:
  WHEN ranking =1 THEN month 
  -- how to populate that number to the rest of the car_type & model pairs?
END AS best_sales_month
```

which ends up with this:

| month | year | car_type | model | sales | ranking | best_sales_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2020 | mercedes | s_class | 2000 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 2020 | mercedes | s_class | 1500 | 2 | NULL |
| 10 | 2020 | bmw | x5 | 7000 | 1 | 10 |
| 11 | 2020 | bmw | x5 | 6000 | 2 | NULL |
| 12 | 2020 | bmw | x5 | 5000 | 3 | NULL |

So essentially, how can I populate the NULL value rows with the 'month' value when 'ranking'=1, for every car_type and model pair?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `first_value(expr)` analytic function that takes the first value of the expression `expr` according to the ordering provided in analytical clause:

> ```
> with input_tab(month, year, car_type, model, sales, ranking) as (
> select 4, 2020, 'mercedes', 's_class', 2000, 1 union all
> select 5, 2020, 'mercedes', 's_class', 1500, 2 union all
> select 10, 2020, 'bmw', 'x5', 7000, 1 union all
> select 11, 2020, 'bmw', 'x5', 6000, 2 union all
> select 12, 2020, 'bmw', 'x5', 5000, 3
> )
>
> select
>   *,
>   first_value(month)
>     over(partition by year, car_type, model order by sales desc) as best_sales_mon
> from input_tab
> ```
>
> ```
> month | year | car_type | model   | sales | ranking | best_sales_mon
> ----: | ---: | :------- | :------ | ----: | ------: | -------------:
>    10 | 2020 | bmw      | x5      |  7000 |       1 |             10
>    11 | 2020 | bmw      | x5      |  6000 |       2 |             10
>    12 | 2020 | bmw      | x5      |  5000 |       3 |             10
>     4 | 2020 | mercedes | s_class |  2000 |       1 |              4
>     5 | 2020 | mercedes | s_class |  1500 |       2 |              4
> ```

Note, that it's the same for most of modern DBMS, so I've used Postgres for [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e45e13efc97cee500c226a13f612abce)

Comment: This works, thank you @astentx! For future visitors, I can confirm that `fist_value(expr)` works also with Google Big Query.